# Php - в строках с датой выбрать минимальную по дате?

Tags: php

Есть строки : '2020-09-23;/var/opt/bc1'  и '2020-07-25;/var/log' и '2020-07-15;/var/opt/bc1'  и т. д. Подкиньте мысль, как выбрать из строк, где путь одинаковый только те, у которых дата наименьшая? Пока думаю так: собрать в массив, где ключами будут пути, а значениями даты. Потом в цикле обойти массив и как-то отобрать те значения, у которых дата меньше при одинаковом ключе.

Comment: правильно, уже бы давно сделал.

Comment: $date_arr = array('0' => '20-05-2015', '1' => '02-01-2015', '2' => '30-03-2015'); for ($i = 0; $i < count($date_arr); $i++) { if ($i == 0) { $max_date = date('Ymd H:i:s', strtotime($date_arr[$i])); $min_date = date('Ymd H:i:s', strtotime($date_arr[$i])); } else if ($i != 0) { $new_date = date('Ymd H:i:s', strtotime($date_arr[$i])); if ($new_date > $max_date) { $max_date = $new_date; } else if ($new_date < $min_date) { $min_date = $new_date; } } } echo date('dm-Y',strtotime($max_date)); echo date('dm-Y',strtotime($min_date));

Comment: для начала у вас каждая строка имеет четкий разделитель на колонки ; соответсвенно это обычный csv читаете его и получаете 2 колонки или сколько у вас там будет. Потом берете и делаете сортировку по дате и array_filter по второй колонке и все у вас будет правильно